# Sql (Oracle) : insert a duplicate key

Tags: sql, oracle

Harry is the wizard and he creates a group which name is “the fellowship of the ring”.Harry’s wizard number is 77.

```
INSERT INTO group VALUES ('the fellowship of the ring','01');
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('01','77','the fellowship of the ring’);
```

Gondor also wants to join the group and the activity01.

From the table, we know “wizardno” is the primary key of the wizard table.

“groupname" is the primary key of the group table. ”acitvityno” is UF key of the group table.

”acitvityno” is the primary key of the activity table.

“groupname” is the foreign key of the activity table.
“wizardno”  is UF key of the activity table.in

to add Gondor to Harry’s group. Gondor’s wizard number is 99.

I use

```
insert into activity values (’01’,’99’,’the fellowship of the ring’);
```

Got the error:
Cause:An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.
For Trusted Oracle configured in DBMS MAC mode, you may see this message if a duplicate entry exists at a different level.
*Action:   Either remove the unique restriction or do not insert the key.

But it must remain the unique restriction.

```
drop table wizard;
drop table activity;
drop table group; 

CREATE TABLE wizard (
    wizardno          NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    wizardname        VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
   );

ALTER TABLE wizard ADD CONSTRAINT wizard_pk PRIMARY KEY ( wizardno );
CREATE TABLE group (
    groupname        VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    activityno         NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE group ADD CONSTRAINT group_pk PRIMARY KEY ( groupname );


CREATE TABLE activity (
    activityno        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    wizardno          CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    groupname         VARCHAR2(30)
);   

ALTER TABLE activity 
   ADD CONSTRAINT activity_pk PRIMARY KEY ( activityno );

ALTER TABLE activity
    ADD CONSTRAINT activity_wizard_fk FOREIGN KEY ( wizardno )
        REFERENCES wizard ( wizardno );
ALTER TABLE  activity
    ADD CONSTRAINT activity_group_fk FOREIGN KEY ( groupname )
        REFERENCES group ( groupname );
```

Comment: Hint:  Do you know what "primary key" means?

Comment: constraint uniquely identifies each record

Comment: @AAlex On a side note `Why the fellowship of the ring` is defined both in group and activity table?

Comment: There are many activities and the group join one of the activities.

Comment: @AAlex As a best practice, refrain from using long descriptions as a key to join tables.

Answer (score 1):

- Do not use a reserved word `group` as a table name
- Use proper single quotes `''` for string type variables
- You need to have corresponding values inserted for look-up tables (
  in this case `wizard` ) which you referenced for decent integrity of
  the tables.
- For Foreign Key and Primary Key relation, both reference columns in
  both tables should be of the same type( you may convert the type of the column `wizardno` from CHAR(2) to number(2) in the `activity` table  ).
- A Primary key column's value shouldn't be duplicated ( here
  constraint name is `activity_pk` )

So the following set of commands may be used :

```
drop table wizard;
drop table activity;
drop table group_; 

CREATE TABLE wizard (
    wizardno          NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    wizardname        VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
   );

ALTER TABLE wizard ADD CONSTRAINT wizard_pk PRIMARY KEY ( wizardno );
CREATE TABLE group_ (
    groupname        VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    activityno         NUMBER(2) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE group_ ADD CONSTRAINT group_pk PRIMARY KEY ( groupname );


CREATE TABLE activity (
    activityno        NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    wizardno          NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    groupname         VARCHAR2(30)
);   

ALTER TABLE activity 
   ADD CONSTRAINT activity_pk PRIMARY KEY ( activityno );

ALTER TABLE activity
    ADD CONSTRAINT activity_wizard_fk FOREIGN KEY ( wizardno )
        REFERENCES wizard ( wizardno );
ALTER TABLE  activity
    ADD CONSTRAINT activity_group_fk FOREIGN KEY ( groupname )
        REFERENCES group_ ( groupname );
INSERT INTO wizard VALUES ( 77, 'Abc');
INSERT INTO wizard VALUES ( 99, 'Def');


INSERT INTO group_ VALUES ('the fellowship of the ring','01');
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('01',77,'the fellowship of the ring');        
INSERT INTO activity VALUES ('02',99,'the fellowship of the ring');
```

Answer (score 1):

- You should not use the `GROUP` keyword as a table name. Instead you could pluralise the table names (`wizards`, `groups`, `activities`).
- `wizardno` is a `NUMBER(2)` type in the wizards table and a `CHAR(2)` in the activities table when there is a foreign key reference between them. They should be the same type.
- You do not need to duplicate `groupname` in the activities table.
- If you do not want to allow duplicate wizards in each group then the primary key on the activity table should be a composite key on both the primary keys of the wizards and groups tables.
- You can use sequences to generate the unique primary key values.

Like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2563b/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE wizards (
  wizardno    NUMBER(2)
              CONSTRAINT wizards_wizardno_pk PRIMARY KEY,
  wizardname  VARCHAR2(30)
              CONSTRAINT wizards_wizardname_nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE wizards_wizardno_seq;

CREATE TABLE groups (
  groupname VARCHAR2(30)
            CONSTRAINT groups_groupname_u UNIQUE
            CONSTRAINT groups_groupname_nn NOT NULL,
  groupno   NUMBER(2)
            CONSTRAINT groups_groupno_pk PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE SEQUENCE groups_groupno_seq;

CREATE TABLE activities (
    activityno NUMBER(2)
               CONSTRAINT activities_activityno_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    groupno    NUMBER(2)
               CONSTRAINT activities_groupno_nn NOT NULL
               CONSTRAINT activities_groupno_fk REFERENCES groups ( groupno ),
    wizardno   NUMBER(2)
               CONSTRAINT activities_wizardno_nn NOT NULL
               CONSTRAINT activities_wizardno_fk REFERENCES wizards ( wizardno ),
    CONSTRAINT activities_group_wizard_u UNIQUE ( groupno, wizardno )
);   

CREATE SEQUENCE activities_activityno_seq;

INSERT INTO wizards ( wizardno, wizardname )
VALUES ( wizards_wizardno_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Harry' );

INSERT INTO wizards ( wizardno, wizardname )
VALUES ( wizards_wizardno_seq.NEXTVAL, 'Gondor' );

INSERT INTO groups ( groupname, groupno )
VALUES ( 'the fellowship of the ring', groups_groupno_seq.NEXTVAL );

INSERT INTO activities ( activityno, groupno, wizardno )
VALUES ( activities_activityno_seq.NEXTVAL, 1, 1 );

INSERT INTO activities ( activityno, groupno, wizardno )
VALUES ( activities_activityno_seq.NEXTVAL, 1, 2 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT wizardname,
       groupname
FROM   wizards w
       INNER JOIN activities a
       ON ( w.wizardno = a.wizardno )
       INNER JOIN groups g
       ON ( a.groupno = g.groupno )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2563b/1/0)**:

```
| WIZARDNAME |                  GROUPNAME |
|------------|----------------------------|
|      Harry | the fellowship of the ring |
|     Gondor | the fellowship of the ring |
```